# Conditional link arm64/armv7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, static-libraries

I have a `.a` library that was compiled only for the `arm64` architecture and I don't have access to the source code.

I added preprocessor flags to disable the usage of the library when compiling under `armv7`

```
#if arch(arm64)
  // Instatiate an object of the library and use it
#else
  // Do nothing (for armv7)
#endif
```

The linking is done via `Other linker flags` but I am getting the error "Invalid bitcode signature" / Linker command failed.

Is there a way to conditionally link the library? I am using Xcode 9

Comment: Have you tried `-weak_library pathToLibrary` in `Other linker flags`?

Comment: What I actually end up doing to silence the compiler is create a FAT library with no compiled code for the other architectures. This would solve the problem as the library is not needed during the linking process.

Comment: Please post this workaround as an answer for benefit of others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I actually end up doing to silence the compiler is create a FAT library with no compiled code for the other architectures. This would solve the problem as the library is not needed during the linking process

Comment: you can also strip the useless arm out when you create the FAT library